# Using jQuery to directly call ASP.NET AJAX page methods -- 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, iis, webmethod

I'm learning about asp methods via ajax and...

So I tried doing the ff. from this site: http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

In JS file:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
// Add the page method call as an onclick handler for the div.
$("#Result").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "WebForm1.aspx/GetDate",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
            $("#Result").text(msg.d);
        }
    });
});
```

});

**In aspx:**

```
 <html>
<head>
<title>Calling a page method with jQuery</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/JScript1.js"></script>
 </head>
  <body>
<div id="Result">Click here for the time.</div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

**In code-behind:**

```
namespace WebApplication1
 {
   public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
    public static string GetDate()
    {
        return DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }

}
```

}

When I run it on VS studio on my local PC, it works just fine; however, once the files are deployed in IIS server, it gives this error when I click on the container:

POST http:///WebForm1.aspx/GetDate 500 (Internal Server Error)

Is there something to configure in IIS? or is it code-related error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try remove this line `[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]` Becouse this line is used When you are trying a Get Request, When you see the Example, they are trying to do a POST request and this lines Is not needed.

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string GetDate()
    {
        return DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Good point, but as suggested by Bart it would be better to turn AJAX call to get instead, as it is indeed to get something from the server, not to post something.

Comment: @Bartdude Thats true I think that I not explain good, but if you see the example that OP posted, you see that He's trying to do a Post Petition.

Comment: Well I see he's trying to call a `Getdate()` method. Anyway your answer is correct and will solve the Op's problem, but better use the proper HTTP methods, especially when you talk about `get` & `post`.

Comment: oh cool! it worked~ I guess I didn't notice the "GET" part, I was trying to do POST. But thanks for the heads up as well @Bartdude thanks guys~ :)

Answer (score 1):

You're doing a POST request to a GET method, try changing your javascript to:

```
$("#Result").click(function () {
    $.get("WebForm1.aspx/GetDate", function (msg) {
        // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
        $("#Result").text(msg.d);
    });
});
```